# Convert Object (can be int, long, string, etc.) to Json Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

So I have a list of maps with dynamic field and values.

E.g.

```
val sampleMap = List(
     Map("field1" -> 1, "field2" -> "helloworld"), 
     Map("field3" -> "abcd", "field4" -> 123.34212543))
```

So basically, I have a variable that is `List[Map[String, Object]]`.

How can I convert this whole thing into a JSON circe?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

Basically we need to match the datatype of the object and convert it to JSON.

```
def toJson(obj: Object): Json = {
      obj match {
        case null                 => Json.Null
        case b: java.lang.Boolean => Json.fromBoolean(b)
        case i: java.lang.Integer => Json.fromInt(i)
        case d: java.lang.Double =>
          Json.fromDouble(d).getOrElse(Json.fromDouble(0d).get)
        case l: java.lang.Long => Json.fromLong(l)
        case t: TemporalAccessor =>
          Json.fromString(DtFormatter.format(t))
        case u => Json.fromString(String.valueOf(u))
      }
    }
```